# Using a printed format used by an application licensed under GNU GPL

Tags: gpl, relicensing

I want to generate [Twibright Optar](http://ronja.twibright.com/optar/) compatible printed pages but I do not want to license my project under GNU GPL license.

The format is simple enough to make a completely new generator tool in few hours without copying any line of code of the original one. This tool will generate PostScript pages ready to print.

Will be legal to deploy this tool under a non-GPL license (with proper attribution of the original work)?

Comment: Unless you're using their code, this has nothing to do with relicensing. What you describe sounds more like reverse-engineering or reimplementation.

Comment: @3D1T0R There are patents and other restrictions on file formats. The format of the output of Twibright Optar is an original creation, so maybe it can be under copyright laws or something else. Because I don't know, I'm asking here.

Comment: Have you considered simply buying a commercial license from the original authors?

Comment: Would MIT-licensed software work for you, such as https://github.com/intra2net/paperbackup ?